# Accessing recipients, body etc in an MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm currently working on persisting the UI state of my iPhone app across launches, but it's proving to be a bit of an issue in one of my controllers - a sub-classed `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Essentially, I need to store (on app exit) the current To/CC/BCC lists, the subject, and the body so I can set the view up again after a relaunch. Unfortunately, Apple seems to have only provided setter methods for this data (e.g. `setToRecipients:`).

No doubt there's some private getters in there somewhere, but I'd rather not risk getting bounced by the App Store approvers...

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is to use `controller.view`, and search for all `UILabel`s in the subview hierarchy.

(Also, there aren't private getters for `MFMailComposeViewController`. Those setters only delegates the message to its internal implementation class.)